# Show dialog box during async processes on sign in

Tags: flutter

I want to show a dialog box to improve user experience during signing as the app has to save some info before navigating to home page. The problem is the dialog box keeps behaving differently at times. Some times the dialog box is shown before navigating to homepage, other times it's shown after navigating and it fails to get hidden

```
PrimaryButton(

text: 'Sign In',

press: () async {

if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {

final message = await AuthService().login(

email: _emailController.text.trim(),

password: _passwordController.text.trim(),

                                );

if (message!.contains('Success')) {

showDialog(

context: context,

builder: (BuildContext context) {

return AlertDialog(

title: const Text('Signing you in...'),

content: Container(

height: 50.0,

width: 50.0,
color: Colors.red,

child: const Center(

child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

                                          ),

                                        ),

                                      );

                                    },

                                  );

final currUserID =

FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

await saveUserModelToHive(currUserID);

await saveSomeInfo();

Navigator.of(context).pop();

if (!mounted) return;

Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(

MaterialPageRoute(

builder: (context) => const LandingPage(),

                                    ),

                                  );

                                } else {

if (!mounted) return;

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

SnackBar(

content: Text(message),

duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),

                                    ),

                                  );

                                }

                              }

                            },

                          ),
```

What could be the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the dialog not showing is that it's running almost at the same time with the code below it and if those ones are fast enough, you'd not even observe the dialog at all.

To solve this, you should put an `await` in front of the showDialog function as it is an asynchronous function OR call the showDialog in a Future.delayed() function.

You can replace the showDialog function with the below code:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
showDialog(

context: context,

builder: (BuildContext context) {

return AlertDialog(

title: const Text('Signing you in...'),

content: Container(

height: 50.0,

width: 50.0,
color: Colors.red,

child: const Center(

child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

                                          ),

                                        ),

                                      );

                                    },

                                  );
         });
```

Better still, to show the user that an operation is ongoing (i.e loading), you could set a variable `isLoading` that would be set to true or false depending on what's currently happening.